# assembly x86 x to the power of b

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

I have a problem with a program that does x^b. It works but stack is not empty.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float a = 1, b = 4, c = 1, d = 1, x = 2, y;
    __asm {
        fld x;
        fld b;
        fyl2x;
        fld st;
        fprem;
        f2xm1;
        fld1;
        fadd;
        fscale;  
        fstp y;
    }
    cout << y;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what i need to do to leave the stack empty

Comment: If you can't pop earlier (e.g. by using a `p` version of an instruction like `faddp`), then pop at the end as many times as necessary with `fstp st`.  Some have an implicit pop, like  `fyl2x` always pops, and there's no non-pop version.  So the name doesn't have a `p`.  But `fscale` doesn't.  So you probably do need to do some manual popping.  It's possible to double-pop with one instructions (`fcomipp`), but IIRC that's usually slower than two `fstp st`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        fld b;
        fld x;
        fyl2x;
        fld st;
        frndint;
        fsub st(1),st;
        fxch;
        f2xm1;
        fld1;
        fadd;
        fscale;
        fstp st(1);
        fstp y
```